# Number of four-digit numbers with restrictions.

Tags: combinatorics

> How many positive four-digit positive integers are there such that the sum of two of their digits is equal to the sum of the other two?

I let the digits of the four digit positive integer be $a,b,c,$ and $d.$ Then, there are $3$ cases to consider: $$a+b=c+d,a+c=b+d,a+d=b+c.$$ I started by just considering one case, which I considered $a+b=c+d.$ Solving how many four-digit positive integers satisfying this, I used stars-and-bars to get $\binom{20}{3}-\binom{11}{3}-3\cdot\binom{10}{3}=615.$ Then, since there are three cases, I multiplied this by $3$ to obtain $1845$ possible three-digit numbers. However, I think I have overcounted or undercounted some cases. Could anyone tell me if I've done anything wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh wait, I have definitely overcounted cases. An example would be when all numbers are the same, such as $3333.$ Should I just subtract the $9$ cases when all the numbers are equal?

Comment: $1845-9=1836$ would still have too many.

Comment: Hmm, am I doing this problem in an incorrect way?

Comment: Oh right, you're correct. There are still too many. Numbers such as $1818$ are still duplicates...

Comment: May I have some help on this problem, or a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps consider separately four cases: all four digits the same, two pairs of the same digits, only one pair the same, and no digits the same. For the last two cases, maybe break it into cases for the value of the sum, from 2 to 16. Then, you’ll also have to make sure not to allow the first digit to ever be 0.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I will try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never know fancy ways to do these problems, but here's my long way:

I get that there are $1584$.

I counted in four cases:

Case 1: all four digits are the same = $9$

Case 2: two pairs = ${10 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2} - 9{3 \choose 1} = 243$

The subtraction is to take away what would be four digits starting with zero.

Case 3: one pair = $228$

Case 4: all digits different = $1104$

For cases 3 & 4, I broke them up into the sums

$$
\begin{align*}
2&: 02 \; 11\\
3&: 03 \; 12\\
4&: 04 \; 13 \; 22\\
5&: 05 \; 14 \; 23\\
&\vdots\\
14&: 59 \; 68 \; 77\\
15&: 69 \; 78\\
16&: 79 \; 88
\end{align*}
$$

Case 3: choose one (matching) pair, and another two with the same sum: $(1+2+3+4+4+3+2+1){4 \choose 2}*2 - 4{3 \choose 1} = 228$

Case 4: all digits different:
$(1+1+3+3+6+6+10+6+6+6+3+3+1)4! - (1+1+2+2+3+3+4)3! = 1104$

Again, the subtractions are taking away what would be four digits starting with zero.

I verified my calculations using the following Python code:

```
import numpy as np
def anyhalf(v,s):
    ans=0
    cnt=0
    for i in range(len(v)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(v)):
            if 2*(v[i]+v[j])==s:
                cnt+=1
    if cnt>0:
        ans=1
    return ans



count = 0
twopair = 0
onepair = 0
alldiff = 0
for a in range(1,10):
    for b in range(10):
        for c in range(10):
            for d in range(10):
                s = a+b+c+d
                x = anyhalf((a,b,c,d),s)
                if x>0:
                    count += 1
                    if len(np.unique([a,b,c,d]))==4:
                        alldiff += 1
                    if len(np.unique([a,b,c,d]))==3:
                        onepair += 1
                    if len(np.unique([a,b,c,d]))==2:
                        twopair += 1
                    
print(f"count={count}")
print(f"twopair={twopair}")
print(f"onepair={onepair}")
print(f"alldiff={alldiff}")
```

Which had the following output:

```
count=1584
twopair=243
onepair=228
alldiff=1104
```